# What is out there in riddle.........?

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

> Press me twice I will run as fast as possible.
>
> Try to read me, and I will become garbage to you.
>
> If you think that I am a beautiful landscape, I will shout at you.

Guess what I am?

Hint :

> The answer is a palindrome word and the title has a clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could be

> A .exe icon

Press me twice I will run as fast as possible.

> If you double click the icon it will execute the file

Try to read me , I will become garbage to you.

> executable binaries are hard to read

If you think I am beautiful landscape , I will shout at you.

> The beautiful landscape it the [Windows wallpaper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knTaY.jpg) behind the icon. Nobody want to be taken for Windows because it is said to be buggy. (Ok this one is a  bit of a stretch)

Hint :

> Answer is palindrome word : "*exe*" is a palindrome

Comment: "If you think I am beautiful landscape , I will shout at you". not same explanation what i had thought.and there is also hint in the title.

Comment: @AmruthA Is it because the code is hidden behind the icon image ?

Comment: it was open exe file as image , open exe file as txt.